# Is "$\emptyset$" always "$\in$" a set or is it "$\subset$" of a set? Homework Help.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set. But I am confused when I looked at that the following question from my assignment and compared it with my solution to the original solution. There you go...

*Question 1.* **Choose the incorrect option.**

$A=\{1,2,\{3,4\},5\}$

(A) $\emptyset\in A$   or (B) $\emptyset\subset A$

From what I know till now is that the correct option is (B), but...

1. Would option (A) be correct if it would have been presented like this--> $A=\{\emptyset,1,2,\{3,4\},5\}$. ---$1$
2. If statement $1$ was the case would $\emptyset\in A$ be correct? and also $\emptyset\subset A$? plus $\{\emptyset\}\subset A$?

Maybe, I am misunderstanding the usage of brackets as well. Kindly help me.
Thank You.

Comment: Correct; $\emptyset \subseteq A$ for every $A$.

Comment: All you said is true

Comment: Use `$\in$` instead of `$\epsilon$` to produce $\in$. Also, there is absolutely no need to separate every symbol with `$ $`. Just put whole expression inside dollar signs together.

Comment: @samjoe It is true, did you notice that OP redefined $A$ ?

Comment: @Adayah Oh missed that. Correct its true then!

Comment: @Ennar gotcha. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right: (B) is the correct option.

If the set were $A=\{\emptyset, 1,2,\{3,4\},5\}$, then we would have $\emptyset\in A$ and $\emptyset \subset A$ and $\{\emptyset\}\subset A$.

Comment: Are you sure? Am I absolutely correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure